# Given a set of transformation values, show T is not a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

---

Hi! 
I'm new to linear transformations.
The question:
Given that 
$T(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, T(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 7 \\ 13 \end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix} and \\ T(\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}, \text{show that T is not a linear map}$

So what I did was firstly, I wanted to find the general vector (x = (x1,y1,z1+). So I solved the following equations:
x + 2y - z = x
2x + y + 4z = y
3x + 7y + 13z = z
which gave me x=y=z=0. That was all I did and now I'm stuck. How would I go about doing this question?

edit: I think I found a way.
Basically I solved the 3 dimensional vectors against the zero vector and found values for x,y,z. Then I multiplied x with (4,1), y with (-1,2) and z with (4,-2) which did not equal to (0,0). Is this a good way? If so, is there a more "concrete" method for these type of questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me what $x$, $y$ and $z$ are in your question. But to show that $T$ is not a linear transformation, you can observe that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\
1 \\
4 \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
7 \\
13 \\
\end{bmatrix} -
3\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
\end{bmatrix} \tag{1}
$$
(By contradiction) If $T$ is a linear transformation, then you should be able to represent $T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\
1 \\
4 \\
\end{bmatrix}\right)$ in terms of $T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
7 \\
13 \\
\end{bmatrix}\right)$ and $T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
\end{bmatrix}\right)$ in a linear form similar to $(1)$. Can you start from here?

Comment: Thanks! This essentially shows that the additive/scalar property doesn't work right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then your method is indeed a good and general way to solve the question. Let me first write your question a little more abstractly:

You are given some map $L$ and some vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$ in the domain and $w_1, \dots, w_k$ in the range such that $L(v_i) = w_i$ and you are asked to show that $L$ cannot be a linear map. What will always work is to try and solve the linear equation

$$ x_1 v_1 + \dots x_k v_k = 0 $$

which, in your case, reads

$$ x \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} + y \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}  + z \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 7 \\ 13 \end{pmatrix} = x v_1 + y v_2 + z v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

A priori, there are two possible cases:

1. The only solution you get is the trivial solution $x_1 = \dots = x_k = 0$. This won't happen because this means that the vectors $v_1, \dots, v_k$ are linearly independent and soon you will probably learn a theorem that says that you can specify a linear map arbitrary on a linearly independent set so in this case, a linear map $T$ that satisfies the equations exists and the question doesn't make sense.
2. You get many non-trivial solutions $x_1, \dots, x_k$. Then you need to check whether $x_1 w_1 + \dots + x_k w_k = 0$. You will necessarily be able to find some non-trivial solution for which $x_1 w_1 + \dots + x_k w_k \neq 0$ which then contradicts the fact that a linear map should map the zero vector in the domain to the zero vector in the range

$$ 0 = T(0) = T(x_1 v_1 + \dots x_k v_k) = x_1 T(v_1) + \dots x_k T(v_k) = x_1 w_1 + \dots x_k w_k \neq 0. $$